# Tengo rutas CRUD, pero no quiero que el usuario acceda directamente sin pasar por el formulario

Tags: laravel

Tengo varios CRUD, por ejemplo:

```
Route::post('/users/create', [App\Http\Controllers\UserController::class, 'store'])->name('users.store');
```

Pero no quiero que el usuario pueda acceder directamente si pone `/users/create`, ya que solo quiero que se puede acceder a esta ruta a través del formulario, sino me salta un error de Laravel, y tampoco sería viable que el usuario directamente accediera a esta ruta sin pasar por el formulario de añadir usuario o registrarse.

Comment: No se entiende... "si pone /users/create" donde? Que formulario? Y a que te refieres con "tampoco sería viable que el usuario directamente accediera a esta ruta sin pasar por el formulario de añadir usuario o registrarse"? Intenta explicar mejor cual es el problema, agrega la información relevante y errores que mencionas. También algún argumento de por qué algo no sería viable. Así como está planteado parece una serie de requerimientos, agrega tambien que intentaste/investigaste para resolver tu problema. Saludos

Comment: A que te refieres con que el usuario acceda usando `"/users/create"`?podría interpretarlo como que se escribe la "url" así sin usar ningún formulario, si es así, entonces se interpreta como un método **`get`** para que puedas evaluar los datos introducidos en el formulario, si son incorrectos pues no debería de redireccionarse la ruta o algo asi.

Comment: Verifica métodos POST o GET según convenga.